# Gauge showing nearly into red

Tags: ford

Gauge goes very quickly nearly into the red zone  coolant in expansion tank is very hot
Not boiled over nor any loss of fluid or leaks. Any ideas,
Faulty stat? Gauge?  Sender unit,?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/make/engine of the vehicle in question? Does it just go up to the red zone and hover? Or does it go up/down? Is the Check Engine light present? If so, what's the codes? Is there any leakage from your coolant system (is it low)?

Comment: Sounds like bad radiator cap. This is likely a duplicate posting.

Comment: Check out posted answers on [this query.](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/25488/mysterious-honda-civic-2002-overheating-some-time/25501#25501)   I'd sure like to know more.  What year, make. model and how many miles on odometer on your vehicle?  Also, where are you located (need your elevation above Sea Level)